# how is the SOLR Service instantiated in DSpace

Tags: dspace

I would appreciate if someone could point me to the way/mechanism used to instantiate the SOLR Service in Dspace 1.8.x. From the configuration dspace.cfg or spring, or conf/modules to the actual registration and instantiation mechanism.

Many thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "instantiated". You need to deploy the solr webapp; communication with Solr is then done by talking to Solr via http.

Comment: I'm just trying trying to understand the integration and how it works. In particular given the version that i have (1.8.x) i was exploring ways to use elastic for a specific use case that i have, unrelated to the search and browse  facilities. Hence i wanted to know how things were done for solr. Based on your comment i checked out that there is a solr on tomcat deployment skim, which probably what you assume as obvious.

Comment: Would then please let me know on the 3.x how Elasticserch is integrated, given that it does not run on tomcat but its own jetty ? My goal is to explore how to use elasticsearch with dspace 1.8.x for a specific use case that i have, which i said above is not related to search and browse. I could indeed deploy elasticSearch on the same machine and use it. But i would like to provide for an integrated appraoch such as what you do for the 3.x

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how this works for Elasticsearch. You might like to ask on the dspace-tech mailing list, I don't know whether anyone familiar with DSpace / Elasticsearch is on Stack Overflow.

Comment: the stackoverflow user peter-dietz is the go to DSpace guy when it comes to Elasticsearch.